# Rails custom scaffolds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, controller, generator, scaffolding

I use two templates to create my controllers in my Rails apps. I've been able to customize my scaffold to handle one of my templates using [this tutorial](http://zigzag.github.io/2010/01/18/customizing-your-scaffold-template-become-easier-in-rails3.html). I was wondering if there is a way to create two scaffolds. I'd like to be able to call `rails generate scaffold1 This` and `rails generate scaffold2 That` and produce my custom controllers.

Comment: `rails generate scaffold This` create for you controller including. if you whant  create  another controller: `rails generate controller NameController action1 etc.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

It's documented [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), and I'll go over the points:

- 'scaffold' is just a 'generator'
- generators are built on [thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor)
- generators themselves have a generator
- You can create your own generators fairly easily by adding files in `lib/generators/`

Example from the page:

> The first step is to create a file at
>   lib/generators/initializer_generator.rb with the following content:
>
> ```
> class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
>   def create_initializer_file
>     create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
>   end
> end
> ```

It's then invoke the generator with `rails generate initializer`, just like you would run `rails generate scaffold` (except the initializer above doesn't accept additional values)